# How to bind data to DataTrigger in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, datagrid, datatrigger

I populate Silverlight `DataGrid` like

```
 grdActivities.ItemsSource = items;
```

**XAML**

```
<datagrid:DataGrid   x:Name="grdActivities" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <sdk:DataGrid.RowStyle>
      <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
         <iv:Interaction.Triggers>
           <ia:DataTrigger Binding=IsMarkedToDelete" Value="True"  >
              <ia:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility" >
                <ia:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                   <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                </ia:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
              </ia:ChangePropertyAction>
           </ia:DataTrigger>
         </iv:Interaction.Triggers>
       </Style>
     </sdk:DataGrid.RowStyle>
  <datagrid:DataGrid.Columns>
   // Some columns are here           
  </datagrid:DataGrid.Columns>
</datagrid:DataGrid>
```

What I cannot get working is `Binding` should it be **relative**?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Binding` must contain the keyword "Binding".

```
<ia:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMarkedToDelete}" Value="True">
```